# Injecting array of values from properties file in spring (without using spring boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

The requirement is the same as the question posted here [Injecting array of values from properties file in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50179656/injecting-array-of-values-from-properties-file-in-spring-boot) i.e. consuming a list of related properties defined in an application.properties file.

The thing is, my code uses Core Spring. How can I achieve the same without having to bring in Spring Boot in order to use @ConfigurationProperties ? Using a comma separated list of values won't work in the long term because i wish to express a list of config objects, not just a list of strings

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can look at using [Apache Commons Configuration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration) which provides rich set of methods to work with properties.

If you want to stick to property files, you can look at using [this page](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html#Lists_and_arrays) for list and arrays:-

```
List<Object> colorList = config.getList("colors.pie");
```

Or you can use XML based [hierarchical configurations](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_hierarchical.html#Hierarchical_Configurations) and use things like:-

```
List<HierarchicalConfiguration<ImmutableNode>> fields = config.configurationsAt("tables.table(0).fields.field");
```

and

```
List<Object> fieldNames = config.getList("tables.table(0).fields.field.name");
```

Read their [user-guide](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/user_guide.html), you should find what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to find a Spring way to accomplish this without having to bring in a third party library.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add the `spring-boot` jar as a dependency you can use `@ConfigurationProperties` with core spring.

```java
package com.stackoverflow.q54119803;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.rules.SpringClassRule;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.rules.SpringMethodRule;

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public class So54119803 {

    /** The Constant SPRING_CLASS_RULE. */
    @ClassRule
    public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE = new SpringClassRule();

    final String anotherPropValue = "anotherPropValue";
    final List<String> expected = Stream.of("string1", this.anotherPropValue)
        .collect(toList());

    /** The spring method rule. */
    @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();

    @Autowired
    Props props;

    @Test
    public void test() {

        System.out.println(this.props);

        assertEquals(this.anotherPropValue, this.props.getAnotherProp());
        assertEquals(String.class, this.props.getClazz());
        assertEquals(this.expected, this.props.getStrings());

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableConfigurationProperties
    static class Config {

        @Bean
        public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {

            final ClassPathResource location = new ClassPathResource("props.properties");
            final PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();

            propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocation(location);
            return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
        }

        @Bean
        @ConfigurationProperties("test")
        Props props() {
            return new Props();
        }

    }

    static class Props {

        String anotherProp;

        List<String> strings;

        Class<?> clazz;

        public String getAnotherProp() {
            return this.anotherProp;
        }

        public void setAnotherProp(String anotherProp) {
            this.anotherProp = anotherProp;
        }

        public List<String> getStrings() {
            return this.strings;
        }

        public void setStrings(List<String> strings) {
            this.strings = strings;
        }

        public Class<?> getClazz() {
            return this.clazz;
        }

        public void setClazz(Class<?> clazz) {
            this.clazz = clazz;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Props [anotherProp=" + this.anotherProp + ", strings=" + this.strings + ", clazz=" + this.clazz
                    + "]";
        }

    }
}
```

Sample props file: `props.properties`

```java
#Conversions and references work fine
test.anotherProp=anotherPropValue
test.strings=string1,${test.anotherProp}
test.clazz=java.lang.String
```

Dependencies in example:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer, but I was hoping to avoid including Spring Boot

Comment: I wasn't sure from you question if you didn't want to be in a spring boot context or if you didn't want to have the jar as a dependency at all.

Comment: I will have the non-boot version up shortly.